# I am trying to make a QT example on VScode

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am a newbie on QT and I am using QT creator 5.8.

What I am doing is to make a QT example named 'Image Composition Example' on VScode. All I have done is make all header and cpp files and copy and paste their contents on VScode. Then I did 'qmake -project' to make .pro file and did make.
After these steps terminal says

```
sangjun@sangjun-All-Series:~/mybuild$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I../anaconda2/include/qt -I../anaconda2/include/qt/QtGui -I../anaconda2/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I../anaconda2/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_imagecomposer.o moc_imagecomposer.cpp
In file included from moc_imagecomposer.cpp:9:0:
imagecomposer.h:5:19: fatal error: QWidget: No such file or directory
 #include <QWidget>
               ^
```

compilation terminated.
    make: *** [moc_imagecomposer.o] Error 1

In this case, how can I deal with it?

Any comments and advices are appreciated.

p.s. I am not so familiar with Linux so I need help in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the results of `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` and `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX`?